# how to read file and remove character before string index

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, file

I have a text file that has the following:

```
hello haha [BS][BS][BS][BS]idk about that [BS][BS][BS][BS]yeah no[BS][BS]
```

I would like to read it and essentially re save it to a new file or just replace the old file using the [BS] as a backspace.
so it would then be...

```
hello idk about yeah
```

Messed around with a bunch of alternatives like .pop() and .replace() no luck unfortunately.

Comment: "hello haha     idk about that     yeah no " is the output of that, I tried that . I'm trying to go back an index and basically use [BS] as a backspace to remove the previous character

Comment: You have a substring 'haha [BS][BS][BS][BS]' Note the space after 'haha'. If you "move back" 4 places, then you'll be left with 'h' but that's not what you show as the required output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT 2:

```py
import re

s = "hello haha [BS][BS][BS][BS]idk about that [BS][BS][BS][BS]yeah no[BS][BS]"

out, i = "", 0
for m in re.finditer(r"(\s*\[BS\])+", s):
    c = m.group(0).count("[BS]")
    out += s[i : max(m.start() - c, 0)]
    i = m.end()
out += s[i:]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
hello idk about yeah
```

---

<sup>Removed `\u0008` version</sup>

Comment: That does **not** work with the sample data shown in the original question. The result would be 'hello hidk about tyeah no'

Comment: Both of these techniques *replace* the [BS] with a backspace character, which is not the same thing as removing them (even if it looks like it did when they are printed).

Comment: it works in the terminal however I am also trying to have it re write to the file with the backspaced characters removed... It writes with the backspace replacing it

Comment: @Oakzeh See my edit 2

Comment: @AndrejKesely  it works!! You are an absolute legend tysm!!!!

Answer (score 0):

this is not the most efficient solution (like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72000424/18344512)), and i'm not sure how you suppose to handle spaces (your description is quite ambiguous - note the comment to your question):

```
from re import sub

s = "hello haha [BS][BS][BS][BS]idk about that [BS][BS][BS][BS]yeah no[BS][BS]"

while '[BS]' in s:
    s = sub(r'.?\[BS\]', '', s, count=1)

>>> s
'''
'hello hidk about tyeah '
```